# Amazon Athena: Alter table to ignore malformed json errors

Tags: json, hive, amazon-athena

This doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE 'table' SET SERDEPROPERTIES( "ignore.malformed.json" = "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that [Athena uses the presto language](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/) not the hive language for DDL. Think of Athen(Presto) as a [subset of the Hive language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/unsupported-ddl.html) while still a full featured ansi-SQL language. The command you are trying to use is [not a supported DDL statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/language-reference.html), sadly.

**You will have to recreate the table** adding the properties:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE impressions (
        id string,        
        awesomeness struct<
           modellookup:string, 
           requesttime:string>     
    )   PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
    ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
    with serdeproperties ( 'ignore.malformed.json'='true' )
    LOCATION 's3://myregion.awesome/awesome';
```

NOT THIS ONE (ignore.malformed.json not available)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE impressions (
        id string,        
        awesomeness struct<
           modellookup:string, 
           requesttime:string>     
    )   PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
    ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
    with serdeproperties ( 'paths'='id' )
    LOCATION 's3://myregion.awesome/awesome';
```

I will add for completeness that is the [latest SerDe documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html)

> **Hive JSON SerDe**
>
> The Hive JSON SerDe is used to process JSON data, most
>   commonly events. These events are represented as blocks of
>   JSON-encoded text separated by a new line.
>
> You can also use the Hive JSON SerDe to parse more complex
>   JSON-encoded data with nested structures. However, this requires
>   having a matching DDL representing the complex data types.
>
> **OpenX JSON SerDe**
>
> This SerDe has a useful property you can specify when
>   creating tables in Athena, to help deal with inconsistencies in the
>   data:
>
> - 'ignore.malformed.json' if set to TRUE, lets you skip malformed JSON
>     syntax.